# How to conditionally cast a type in dart?

Tags: dart, casting

It seems if it's just a variable, I can conditionally cast like this.

```
Animal animal = Dog();
if (animal is Dog) {
  animal.bark(); // animal is of type Dog here
}
```

But if it's a property on a class, how do I conditionally cast?

```
House house = House()
house.animal = Dog();
if (house.animal is Dog) {
  house.animal.bark(); // fail
}
```

I know I can do it like this

```
if (house.animal is Dog) {
  Dog animal = house.animal;
  animal.bark();
}
```

But that seems cumbersome. Is there anyway I can check and cast type in one go like I can with variables?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your last example won't actually work if you disable implicit casts.  It instead should use `Animal animal = house.animal; if (animal is Dog) { animal.bark(); }`.

Comment: BTW, if you're curious *why* type promotion doesn't happen on fields, see: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/104

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## tl;dr

Replace multiple field accesses by a local variable.

```dart
final house = House()..animal = Dog()
final animal = house.animal;

if (animal is Dog) {
  animal.bark();
} else if (animal is Cat) {
  animal.meow();
} else if (animal is Wolf) {
  animal.howl();
}
```

## Complete answer

This is a Dart limitation. It happens because the compiler cannot guarantee that the result of the first access to `animal` is the same as the second access. Even is the field is final, a subclass may override its getter to change the return value at different accesses.

Check [the adapted example below from Leaf Petersen](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/104#issuecomment-440387074). (Thanks [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) for mentioning.)

```dart
class A {
  final num x = 3;
}

class B extends A {
  num y = 3;
  num get x => y;
}

void main() {
  B b = B();
  A a = b;
  if (a.x is int) {
    b.y = 3.0;
    (a.x as int).isEven; // Fall down go boom.
  }
}
```

One way to work around that is by avoiding multiple field accesses. This can be done by assigning the result of the field access to a local variable such as:

```dart
final house = House()..animal = Dog()
final animal = house.animal;

if (animal is Dog) {
  animal.bark();
} else if (animal is Cat) {
  animal.meow();
} else if (animal is Wolf) {
  animal.howl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a conditional type cast like the example below:

```dart
class MyException implements Exception {
  int customCode = 2;
}

void myFunc(){
  //you can switch between the values below to see the effect
  // throw Exception();
  throw MyException();
}

void main() {
  try {
    myFunc();
  } catch (e) {
    final i = e is MyException ? e.customCode : -10;
    print(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better solution to use interfaces.

```
abstract class Animal {
  void doSound(); // each animal does sound
}

class Dog implements Animal {
  @override
  void doSound() {
    print('wof');
  }
}

class Cat implements Animal {
  @override
  void doSound() {
    print('meow');
  }
}
```

```
House house = House()
house.animal = Dog();
animal.doSound();
house.animal = Cat();
animal.doSound();
```